# Android Text-To-Speech throws ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I applied text-to-speech to my app (as the procedure shown [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)). It works flawlessly on most of the devices. But in some devices such as `LG Optimus G, GK, L3 II and Sky IM-A800S`, the app activity stops unexpectedly with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.appname/com.myapp.appname.ContentView}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA }
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4827)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1568)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1439)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
at viettien.kadict.ContentView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
... 11 more
```

And here is my brief code:

```
private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 4;
private TextToSpeech tts;

onCreate()
    //Fire off an intent to check if a TTS engine is installed
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

OnButtonClick
    SpeakText("Here is the word spoken");

onDestroy()
    tts.stop();
    tts.shutdown();

onActivityResult
    case MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE:

        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)  
        {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else
        {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);  
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }

        break;

onInit
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

         int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {

        }     
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

SpeakText
     tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Is this a ROM-related problem or there is something wrong with my code?

Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

The error indicated that the `Activity` named `android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA` has not been exported as part of the ROM (Note: LG ROMs have been known to be problematic.) To prevent this error just do this:

```
try {
   Intent intent = new Intent(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   context.startActivity(intent);   
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
   Log.e("Oops! The function is not available in your device." + e.fillInStackTrace());
}
```

Another method you can use is check first whether a package is callable, like:

```
public static boolean isActivityCallable(Context context, String packageName, String className) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);        
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager(context).queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Where `packageName` is `TextToSpeech.Engine` and `className` is `TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA`

Comment: Many thanks to you. Your solutions looks promising. I applied the first method but a user of `LG Optimus G (geehrc)` running Android 4.4 still reports the same problem: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.INSTALL_TTS_DATA }`. That's so annoying!!!

Comment: @NiamhDoyle: Use the second solution, such that if the Activity is not callable, you just display a message to your LG users that they cannot use this particular TTS feature. This way, LG device owners can complain back to LG so they can make the changes. Like I said before, there are other Activities LG have not exported to their ROMs that causing much grieve not just to me, but other developers as well.

Comment: I'm trying to use the second solution but I'm always getting an empty list. I tested the solution over ten different devices: Google Pixel 5, and 6, samsung sm-g9*, docomo sh, and others... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Check the SDK that you are running in that particular device. TexttoSpeech API has been introduced only from Android 1.6 SDK. So if you running 1.5 SDK you might face this issue.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

There has been already an issue that has been filed on the same. Probably you need to change the conditions a bit.

Check if your intent is actually supported

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent installIntent = new Intent();
installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity( installIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );

if( resolveInfo == null ) {
   // Not able to find the activity which should be started for this intent
} else {
   startActivity( installIntent );
}
```