# Android: check if activity is callable

Tags: java, android

I need to check if an activity is callable and I'm using this method:

```
public boolean isActivityCallable(String packageName, String className) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);        
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager(context).queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

but something is not working.

If I check, for example, if TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA is callable (and I assume this is a very common and widely supported check) I get that the activity is not callable on many different devices: Google Pixel 5 and 6, samsung sm-g9*, docomo sh, and others...

I'm calling the method like this:

```
isActivityCallable("TextToSpeech.Engine", "TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA");
```

**Am I calling Intent.setClass name with wrong parameters?**
I tried also to use the full package name (android.speech.tts) but the result is the same.

Some reference:

- [Android Text-To-Speech throws ActivityNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830230/android-text-to-speech-throws-activitynotfoundexception)
- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Comment: SetClassName isn't the right way to do this.  That's looking for a package with the name and class in it.  Neither of those things are package names or classes.  Instead, you want to use the Intent(String action) constructor and not set a component name.

Comment: I tried with 
```Intent intent = new Intent("TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA"); ```
but the result is the same...

Comment: Ok trivial error... TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA is a final String and it contains the right String to be checked. So calling ```Intent intent = new Intent(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);``` without quotes it's working